Deneb - Vega require to understand Javascript?
I am trying to learn how to use Vega/Vegalite to produce a visualisation.
I am just wondering, do I need to have a basic understanding of JavaScript in order for me to understand Vega ?
Thanks Heaps for your help and guidance in advance.
I have been going through some feeds to understand where to begin with.

No, JavaScript knowledge is not required. Vega and Vega-Lite are declarative and have their own Grammar of Graphics syntax to create plots. JavaScript can be useful if writing expressions using signals but even then the expressions are typically quite straight forward.

Thanks for the reply ! I've seen lots of great stuffs of your work. Thanks for sharing as always.
